# Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Match propertyof the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: vba, excel, match

In my macro, I have the following code :

```
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(str_accrual, Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)), 0)
```

where 'str_accrual'  is a string captured earlier to this line and the Range selected is in a single row say from "A1" to "BH1" and the result will be a number which is the position of that string in that range selected.

When I run the macro, I get the error:

> Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Match propertyof the WorksheetFunction class

But when I run the macro line by line using (F8) key, I don't get this error but when I run the macro continuously I get the error. Again, if the abort the macro and run it again the error doesn't appear.

Comment: The `find` range method works as well.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: This may or maynot help your answer, but try sorting your data before applying your macro. What I have noticed while doing this is everytime I have 2 errors back to back this error pops up. Something about multiple errors doesn't allow the code to move forward. In my case I'm able to apply a sort that for the most part eliminates this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried several times. It seems that if there is no match, the expression will prompt this error

if you want to catch the error, use `Application.Match` instead

Then you can wrap it with `isError`

Answer (score 1):

tons of posts on this error but no solution as far as I read the posts.  **It seems that for various worksheet functions to work, the worksheet must be active/visible**.  (That's at least my latest finding after my Match() was working randomly for spurious reasons.)

I hoped the mystery was solved, though activating worksheets for this kind of lookup action was a pain and costs a few CPU cycles.

So I played around with syntax variations and it turned out that the code started to work after I removed the underscore line breaks, regardless of the worksheet being displayed. <- well, for some reason I still had to activate the worksheet :-(

'does not work

```
'Set oCllHeader = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Cells(oCllSpielID.Row, _
                    Application.Match( _
                        strValue, _
                        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Range( _
                            oCllSpielID, _
                            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Cells(oCllSpielID.Row, lastUsedCellInRow(oCllSpielID).Column)), _
                            0))
```

**'does work (removed the line breaks with underscore for readibility) <- this syntax stopped working later, no way around activating the worksheet :-(**

```
Set oCllHeader = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Cells(oCllSpielID.Row, Application.Match(strValue, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Range(oCllSpielID, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Cells(oCllSpielID.Row, lastUsedCellInRow(oCllSpielID).Column)), 0))
```

In the end I am fretting running into more realizations of this mystery and spending lots of time again.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error intermittently. Turns out, it happened when I had a different worksheet active.

As the docs for Range say,

> When it's used without an object qualifier (an object to the left of the period), the Range property returns a range on the active sheet.

So, to fix the error you add a qualifier:

```
Sheet1.Range
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue using a third-party generated xls file that the program was pulling from.  When I changed the export from the third-party program to xls (data only) it resolved my issue.  So for some of you, maybe there is an issue with pulling data from a cell that isn't just a clean value.

I apologize if my nomenclature isn't great, just a novice to this.

Answer (score 0):

That is what you get if MATCH fails to find the value.

Comment: But I am able to find the match when I run the macro line by line ! And I don't get the error all the time. when I get the error, I abort the macro and try running again, I don't see the error. It finds the match and macro runs fine after that.

Comment: Have you altered your selection in the process inadvertently?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(str_accrual, Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)), 0)) Then
    i = Application.Match(str_accrual, Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)), 0)
Else
    'do something if no match is found

End If
```

**Update**

Here is better code that does not rely on `Selection` except as a means of user-input for defining the range to be searched.

```
Sub Test()

Dim str_accrual As String
Dim rngToSearch As Range

str_accrual = InputBox("Search for?")

Set rngToSearch = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))

If Not IsError(Application.Match(str_accrual, rngToSearch, 0)) Then
    i = Application.Match(str_accrual, rngToSearch, 0)
    MsgBox i
Else
    MsgBox "no match is found in range(" & rngToSearch.Address & ")."
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks David. I tried your code, but again...as I kept saying, the error appears every now and then but not all the time. Just a mystery to solve.

Comment: This code *cannot* create the errors you're experiencing -- specifically because it's not calling the `_WorksheetFunction.Match` . Since `Application.Match` allows to be wrapped in the `IsError` function which traps errors that would otherwise be raised by the `WorksheetFunction.Match`.   As others asked, it's possibly you altered the `Selection` (you should not rely on this construct except for sometimes as a means of user-input, but never as a variable/object).   Or, possibly if you are calling this macro with multiple workbooks open, an error could happen based on which book is "Active".

Comment: Note: revised code, answer was missing the `Then` in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I used "If Not IsError" and the error kept showing. To prevent the error, add the following line as well:

On Local Error Resume Next

Answer (score 0):

when nothing is found, Match returns data type Error, which is different from a number.  You may want to try this.

```
dim result variant
result = Application.Match(....)
if Iserror(result)
    then not found
    else do your normal thing
```