# Excel VBA Worksheet Function Match Produces Error When Value Does Not Exist

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, match

I attempted to use the MATCH function in Excel VBA coding. When I enter a part number and the MATCH function is able to locate the row in which it exists, no error occurs. However, when the value being searched for does not exist, I receive an error message that says it is "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class". It classifies this a run-time error '1004'.

Since it produces this type of error, I am unable to use the iserror function or a set of if statements to try to parse it out; both values will always be FALSE.

If there is a way to avoid this error please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

[Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Match propertyof the WorksheetFunction class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030786/run-time-error-1004-unable-to-get-the-match-propertyof-the-worksheetfunction-c)

Sam092 has recommended that the application version of MATCH be used and wrapped with IsError. This works perfectly.