# VBA data transfer to other workbook based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, copy, match

I have two opening workbooks. I tried to copy the existing note from one workbook to another if the student record matches. Below is my code. However, the run-time error '91' appears that Object variable or With block variable not set. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function SheetFromCodeName(aName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    If sh.CodeName = aName Then
       Set SheetFromCodeName = sh
       Exit For
    End If
Next sh
End Function

Sub Note_Transfer()
Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim MatchRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim sh_old As Worksheet
Dim sh_new As Worksheet

Set sh_old = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", Workbooks(Workbooks.Count - 1))
Set sh_new = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", Workbooks(Workbooks.Count))

For i = 2 To lastrow
If Cells(i, 25) <> "New student" Then
MatchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 23).Value, sh_new.Range("W:W"), 0)
sh_old.Range(Cells(MatchRow, 26), Cells(MatchRow, 32)).Copy _
Destination:=sh_new.Range(Cells(i, 26), Cells(i, 32))

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: In which line is the error poping up? Thought   `If sh.CodeName = Name Then` should be `If sh.CodeName = aName Then`

Comment: I think `If sh.CodeName = Name Then` should be `If sh.CodeName = aName Then`. The error message isn't 100% clear, but in that function you have no variable named `Name`. And `Name` itself is a reserved word in VBA (for copying files to a new location), so perhaps that's where the error message becomes more clear :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response! The origin error hit the line of MatchRow = Application.... I corrected the function if part. But new error popped up that '1004' Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction Class.

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030786/run-time-error-1004-unable-to-get-the-match-propertyof-the-worksheetfunction-c) help?

Comment: About the `Name` thing - specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of every module would help.

Comment: If you get 1004, it means that it can't find the value you try to find in the range. Are you positive that the value is in there?

Comment: Thank you, guys! However, after some modification, the bug 1004 still there. I am positive that the value is in the referred column. The issue posted in the link here is similar. However, even though I run with F8, the bug did not disappear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030786/run-time-error-1004-unable-to-get-the-match-propertyof-the-worksheetfunction-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help! The modified code is pasted below. And it works well.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function SheetFromCodeName(aName As String, wb As Workbook) As Worksheet

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        If sh.CodeName = aName Then
           Set SheetFromCodeName = sh
           Exit For
        End If
    Next sh

End Function

Sub Note_Transfer()


    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim MatchRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh_old As Worksheet
    Dim sh_new As Worksheet

    Set sh_old = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", Workbooks(Workbooks.Count - 1))
    Set sh_new = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", Workbooks(Workbooks.Count))

    sh_new.Activate

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow

    If Cells(i, 25) <> "New patient" Then

    MatchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 23).Value, sh_old.Range("W:W"), 0)

    sh_new.Range(sh_new.Cells(i, 26), sh_new.Cells(i, 32)).Value = sh_old.Range(sh_old.Cells(MatchRow, 26), sh_old.Cells(MatchRow, 32)).Value

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Worksheet.CodeName is **not** a string. It is a Worksheet Object and cannot be compared to a string, even if that string looks like the CodeName.

Comparing the CodeName's Name to the string will compare a string to a string. Force both to either upper or lower case to avoid false negatives based upon case.

```
Public Function SheetFromCodeName(aName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Worksheet

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        If lcase(sh.CodeName.Name) = lcase(Name) Then
           Set SheetFromCodeName = sh
           Exit For
        End If
    Next sh

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation! However, the bug says invalid qualifier at the line of sh.CodeName.Name